# Is a cgroup a list of key value pairs or a set of processes?

Tags: cgroups

I get the idea that a cgroup is a set of processes satisfying some conditions, from http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/cgroups.7.html

> A cgroup is **a collection of processes** that are bound to a set of
>   limits or parameters defined via the cgroup filesystem.

Am I correct that to find out the cgroup of a process with a givn PID, just run

```
$ cat /proc/11/cgroup
12:perf_event:/
11:blkio:/
10:hugetlb:/
9:freezer:/
8:pids:/
7:cpuset:/
6:devices:/
5:cpu,cpuacct:/
4:rdma:/
3:memory:/
2:net_cls,net_prio:/
1:name=systemd:/
0::/
```

I thought cgroup is a id number. but it is a list of key value pairs.
Does the above list of key value pairs represent a list of processes?

Can I find out all the processes in the same cgroup?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

As indicated in the manual page you’re referring to, a cgroup is a set of processes.

The contents of `/proc/11/cgroup` describe all the control groups to which process 11 belongs. For v1 groups, the first field on each line is the hierarchy id, the second is the list of controllers, and the third is the pathname of the cgroup in the hierarchy. For v2 groups, the first field is 0, the second is empty, and the third is the pathname.

To find all the processes in a cgroup, look at the `tasks` file in the corresponding sysfs directory, for example

```
cat /sys/fs/cgroup/perf_event/tasks
```

which corresponds to `12:perf_event:/`:

```
| /sys/fs/cgroup/ | perf_event | / | tasks
|                 |            |   |
|<  mountpoint   >|<controller>| ^ |
                                 |
               cgroup pathname --+
```

Comment: Thanks. `perf_event` isn't a cgroup but a controller. So `/sys/fs/cgroup/perf_event/tasks` seems to find all processes for a controller

Comment: You’re forgetting the third field in `12:perf_event:/`.

Comment: (1) The third field is "the pathname of the cgroup in the hierarchy", here `/`.  Is it a relative pathname with respect to some other pathname?  (2)  Does `/sys/fs/cgroup/perf_event/tasks` depend on the third field? also on the second field, which is a list of controllers?

Comment: I posted a related post https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/511066/does-each-directory-under-sys-fs-cgroup-represent-a-cgroup-hierarchy

Comment: You really don’t see how `/sys/fs/cgroup/perf_event/tasks` is contructed, based on the information in `12:perf_event:/`?

Comment: I don't actually understand the structure under `/sys/fs/cgroup/`, in relation to cgroups, their hierarchies and controllers, as shown in this post and the other post. Really, I am not sure.

Comment: OK, see the update, hopefully that clarifies things in the context of this particular question.

Comment: As I’ve said before, try *using* this stuff to figure out what’s going on; I get the impression you’re trying to understand the documentation without using anything.

Comment: Thanks. I tried something similar to your last comment, and then have some difficulties there  in the other post https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/511066/does-each-directory-under-sys-fs-cgroup-represent-a-cgroup-hierarchy-or-a-c.

Answer (score 1):

Stephen Kitt mocks you explaining the path structure on bad example. So the good example is following. Lets list tasks in the cpu controller cgroup related to the process PID 1595. `cat /proc/1595/cgroup` gives us

```
12:hugetlb:/
11:rdma:/
10:net_cls,net_prio:/
9:freezer:/
8:blkio:/system.slice/containerd.service
7:cpuset:/
6:cpu,cpuacct:/system.slice/containerd.service
5:devices:/system.slice/containerd.service
4:pids:/system.slice/containerd.service
3:memory:/system.slice/containerd.service
2:perf_event:/
1:name=systemd:/system.slice/containerd.service
0::/system.slice/containerd.service
```

The cpu controller line is `6:cpu,cpuacct:/system.slice/containerd.service` hence the list of processes in the group can be read from `/sys/fs/cgroup/cpu/system.slice/containerd.service/tasks`. Note that the `tasks` file also list threads. This path represents the hierarchical structure of cgroups resource allocation, `system.slice` is the parent group to `containerd.service`. Stephen is explaining this on the root path example with just one `/` in the path which really makes no sense.

If you only need a quick look on the hierarchy, you may just call `systemd-cgls cpu` which examine this low level procfs files for you and draw a nice tree.